# Django Rest Framework Session + Token Auth issue

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, django-2.0

Hello again all wonderful experts helping noobs like me!

This time in my DRF api I am using token auth but before I upgraded to django2 and python3, session auth worked as well at least from my computer to my server. Now if I run it on local host during development and I login to my admin panel at /admin(django admin) then go to /docs(swagger UI) I can only see the URLS that do not require a login. However, the csrf token and session is being properly set, but django is not recognizing the user. Is it because it's localhost? I have the same issue getting the session for two-factor so I hacked it so I don't need it but I'm wondering if I should test it pushing to my production server under a test environment or can you see maybe I have a stupid error in my settings? Also if there's anything else you want to see just let me know and I'll post it. Thanks a lot!

** edit **
My admin panel auto logs in and properly gets the user from the session.

---

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
)
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'mysite.middleware.AnonymousAccessMiddleware',
'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
]
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
"exclude_namespaces": [], # List URL namespaces to ignore
'USE_SESSION_AUTH': True,
"api_version": '0.1',  # Specify your API's version
"api_path": "/",  # Specify the path to your API not a root level
"enabled_methods": [  # Specify which methods to enable in Swagger UI
    'get',
    'post',
    'put',
    'patch',
    'delete'
],
"api_key": 'my token', # An API key
"is_authenticated": True,  # Set to True to enforce user authentication,
"is_superuser": True,  # Set to True to enforce admin only access
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out. It wasn't the middleware, it was the mixin checking the login that when you run the code via the middleware to validate the token it takes the user and discards it then authorizes it based on the token. So instead of modifying the oAuth provider instead I just left it so it only takes in the token and then I created my own two-factor system.